# Sql Server Backup Sizes

Tags: sql-server, compression, backup

Does anyone have real world experience of backup compression in Sql 2008, I'd like to know how it performs compared to Sql 2005 + winrar. Currently when I back up a I get a 14G file. Using rar shrinks it to <400M, a massive saving. Most of the data is similar, being figures from the stock market so I guess that makes it easy to compress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figures I have seen suggest compression ratios in the range 3 - 4.5 times smaller, which is not as good as the figures you quoted for rar. See [Tuning the Performance of Backup Compression in SQL Server 2008](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/04/21/tuning-the-performance-of-backup-compression-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

On a side note, creating compressed backups is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Time to restore is an important thing for backups.  If you compress your backups, you will spent more time to restore it.

Comment: Yep, I agree but I back up 100 times for every one off restore that I have to do, unless it's a bad week.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one that goes from 200GB down to 50GB, definitely not as compact as WinRar is getting you, but a lot more convenient. As others have noted, backup time is quicker, but restore time is (a bit) longer but still way quicker than  SQL2000.